# Is there any way I can ease Excel's UTF-8 handling using PHP?

Tags: php, excel, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have been having some very peculiar UTF-8 behaviour from a couple of scripts that import and export information to/from a database via CSV files, especially the way Excel handles them.

The scripts themselves are not particularly complex, and I believe I'm setting the encoding correctly (for the sake of brevity, I have excluded error handling and character escaping code):

**Import**

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

require_once("inc.db.php"); // database connection
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$csv = $_FILES['csv'];
$handle = fopen($csv['tmp_name'], "r");

while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',', '"')) {
    $first_name = $data[0];
    $family_name = $data[1];
    $company = $data[2];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET first_name = '$first_name', etc...);
}
```

**Export**

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"); // utf-8 bom
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF8");

require_once("inc.db.php"); // database connection
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

echo "FIRST NAME,FAMILY NAME,COMPANY,\n";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, family_name, company FROM table");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '"' . $first_name . '","' . $family_name. '","' . $company. '",\n';
}

// Alternate attempt at looping below

$array = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $data;
}
$x = fopen("php://output", "w");
foreach ($array as $fields) {
    fputcsv($x, $fields);
}
fclose($x);
```

To my eye, both of these scripts work fine, no problems so far. However, when I open and work on the exported CSV file in Excel, this is where the interesting stuff begins.

The information in the database contains foreign latin characters like `é` and `Ü`. These store correctly (the MySQL database encoding is `utf8_unicode_ci`), still no problems yet.

However, only two of the three scenarios work correctly. But guess what, the one that doesn't work (Scenario Two) is the one I need to work... isn't that always the way?

---

**Scenario One**

I export a CSV file, and then re-import it immediately. I never open or modify the file in any way.

*Unfortunately, this is a pointless exercise. It does work, though.*

---

**Scenario Two**

I export a CSV file, open it, modify the contents, save, and then re-import.

*Interesting note: when I choose "Save" from the dialogue menu in Excel, it saves as a "Unicode Text" file instead of overwriting the CSV file. This new file still opens in Excel, but the data is corrupt. I need to choose "Save As..." and select "Comma Separated Values" from the file type menu. I have also attempted to choose UTF-8 from the encoding menu on this step.*

The problem with this scenario lies in the foreign characters: as soon as the import script reaches one of them, it simply *stops writing that field* to the database. No corrupt characters `â€`. No little question marks `�`. Simply, nothing. However, the rest of the data in that row of the CSV is written fine.

---

**Scenario Three**

I export a CSV file, open it, modify the contents, save, open in a text editor, re-save with UTF-8 encoding, then re-import.

*Hurrah, it works! However, I can't expect the users of this system to play about with text editors and encodings - they should be able to export > edit > save > import seamlessly.*

---

**My Thoughts on What Is Going Wrong™**

1. Something in one of my scripts (probably the import) is not handling the encoding correctly.
2. Something in one of my scripts (probably the export) is not correctly creating a CSV file, hence the Unicode Text file type on the Save dialogue.
3. Excel just *really* doesn't like UTF-8 files, and there's nothing I can do.

Please tell me the fault here lies with me, and there's a way I can get around this!

Comment: Are you using Excel on Mac or Windows? I know I had some problems with Excel on Mac compared to Windows with different encodings.

Comment: This is on Windows, Office 2010 and 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Excel the `Unicode Text` Save As option writes out a tab delimited unicode file, but Windows being what it is, writes it in UTF16. Your import is probably anticipating UTF-8 and so once it hits the oddballl 2-byte UTF-16LE encoded foreign character it barfs on itself and gives up.

You can use linux command `iconv -f UTF-16LE -t utf8 yourfile.address > yourfile.address.tmp` to convert, or change your import script to accept UTF-16LE encoded data.

Comment: The thing is, when I Save As, I switch it back to the comma delimited type.

Comment: Neither the `iconv()` or `mb_convert_encoding()` functions work either.

Comment: So you open the file in Excel, then you Save As Unicode Text, then you open it again? If you open it again and Save As CSV it's going to no longer be unicode. In excel, at least in my experience, you can't get it to export a file as both comma delimited AND unicode. So I export as Unicode, and then swap the delimiter and convert utf16le to utf8 with another program. LibreOffice Calc, on the other hand, lets you specify the encoding AND the delimiter when you export, so you might be better off switching to that program.

Comment: No, open the file the first time and save straight to a comma delimited file. I never deal with a unicode text file at all - it's just the default selected option in the "save as type" dropdown when I choose Save As.

Comment: Gotcha. So... if you Save As... CSV in excel you are going to have a non-unicode comma delimited file. You are then trying to import that non-unicode file as UTF-8, which doesn't seem like it should cause the import to bork, but even the best case scenario would have a 100% import, but all of your foreign characters would be lost to whatever stand-in ASCII/Latin character that excel uses.

Comment: Yeah, playing about with things even more dumbfounds me as to how Excel works. If I remove my BOM echo from the start of the export, the foreign characters are fudged, but Save As defaults to CSV. It seems like if Excel finds a BOM, it wants to save as UTF-16LE tab delimited, but even if you manually change it to UTF-8 and/or comma delimited, it just removes the BOM... which fails the import. Sigh...

Comment: Yep. Excel is not friendly with unicode and delimiters with exports :(. I have a process for folks that send me unicode data from foreign countries. They primarily work in Excel and are not technical folks, so I just have them "Save As... Unicode Text" in Excel, then I have a bash script that swaps the tabs for pipes, clears out the double quote string encapsulation, and converts the file from UTF-16LE to UTF8 and then I import it. I feel your pain.

Comment: We currently do a similar thing with other files - save as unicode text, wrap each column in double quotes, convert commas to a placeholder `%COMMA%`, convert tabs to commas, and then upload, changing back the placeholders. I wonder if it's possible to do it all, on-the-fly, in the import script... I doubt it.

Comment: Our process is all done manually, and it gets even more convoluted when we need to deal with non-latin characters...